# pandas - vectorized code slower than for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have two functions that give the same result, one vectorized and one with a "for" loop. Suprisingly the for loop is faster than the vectorized version. Any idea why is it so ?

```
def loop_for(df):
    gpd    = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq="QS-JAN"), 'CD_PDP'])
    result = []
    for (quarter, unite), data in gpd:
        nb_MAT_RH   = data["MAT_RH"  ].nunique()
        nb_MAT_RHPI = data["MAT_RHPI"].nunique()
        result.append({"CD_PDP": unite, "MOIS_COMPTABLE": quarter, "nb_mat_rh" : nb_MAT_RH, "nb_MAT_RHPI" : nb_MAT_RHPI})

    return pd.DataFrame(result)


def vectorisation(df):
    b = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq="QS-JAN"), 'CD_PDP']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series( {"nb_mat_rh"   : x["MAT_RH"  ].nunique(),
                                                                                          "nb_MAT_RHPI" : x["MAT_RHPI"].nunique()}))
    return b.reset_index()
```

when testing :

```
import timeit
print "loop"
print timeit.timeit(stmt="loop_for(df)",number= 2, setup="from __main__ import loop_for; from __main__ import df")
print "vector"
print timeit.timeit(stmt="vectorisation(df)",number= 2, setup="from __main__ import vectorisation; from __main__ import df")
```

it gives :

```
loop
6.83789801598
vector
7.13991713524
```

Comment: Using `.apply(lambda ... )` is not really vectorization; it is essentially the same as running a `for` loop over the data.

Comment: Also, we have no idea what `df` you're passing to your functions.  But more importantly... what @ajcr said.

Comment: good to know :) Would vectorization be possible here ? And if so how ?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `.nunique()` on a `SeriesGroupBy` object does take advantage of vectorization:

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq="QS-JAN"), 'CD_PDP'])

b = df.groupby('a').agg({'MAT_RH': 'nunique', 'MAT_RHPI': 'nunique'})
b = b.rename(columns={'MAT_RH': 'nb_mat_rh', 'MAT_RHPI': 'nb_MAT_RHPI'})
```

But without even a sample of your original `df` it is impossible to run any benchmarks.

Comment: @romainjouin, please consider accepting an answer it was helpful

Comment: @romainjouin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.